# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find <...> with 'id'=):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

**Note** : I'm new to RoR ; My syntax is `haml`

In a `view`, I'm using a param in an if statement as follow :

`- if @progress_board.cover_image.present?`

Every time my code is reaching it, I get the following error :

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find ProgressBoard with 'id'=):
app/controllers/progress_boards_controller.rb:340:in `get_panel_data'
```

First, `cover_image` is declared in my ProgressBoard `model`. I'm sure this is working since I managed to display this `cover_image`.

In my `controller`, `@progress_board` is declared in my method :

```
  def get_panel_data
        @progress_board = ProgressBoard.find(params[:progress_board_id])
   ...
  end
```

Here is my `route.rb` file part related to the issue :

```
  resources :progress_boards do
    collection do
      get :get_progress_data
      get :get_panel_data
      get :render_tab
    end
    member do
      get :open_or_archive
      get :pbbackground
      get :remove_cover
      get :get_panel_data
    end
  end
```

I already tried to replace `(params[:progress_board_id])` with `(params[:progress_board])` and `(params[:id])` but none made the trick

What am I missing ?

Comment: It should be `params[:id]` and the error is because the `id` you are sending does not correspond with a persisted `ProgessBoard`

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving an error because of this line:

`@progress_board = ProgressBoard.find(params[:progress_board_id])`

The value in `params[:progress_board_id]` does not correspond to a value in the `id` column of your ProgressBoard table.

You need to ensure that the param you are passing will exist in the `id` column in your table.

You can use `@progress_board = ProgressBoard.find_by(id: params[:progress_board_id])` which will not cause an exception if the value isn't in the DB table.

Comment: Doing this I get the following error :
`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `cover_image' for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: Yes because your trying to call `cover_image` on a nil object.. Ensure that the param you pass actually exists in the DB and it won't be nil

Comment: How could I check this ?

Comment: Read this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-a-single-object